# Is still within answering guidelines?

Tags: discussion, answers, guidelines

I have been answering on StackOverflow for some time, but recently ran into a situation where I might have been in the wrong. If I am wrong, I would like to correct it in the proper way.

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976711/take-picture-from-device-screen-content-not-a-view-programmatically-in-android/10977379#10977379) answer in response to a fairly often repeated topic. It references a known application of which several working versions demonstrate the capability required by the OP. This resulted in a small discussion with another high rep member.

What I need to know is:

a) Is it incorrect to point to a known solution on the market even when its mechanics are unknown?

b) Is it considered improper to reference a solution for which there is not directly supported API on the specific platform?

I ask this because I was made to feel that the answer was not acceptable due to these circumstances, and I do not believe that was the correct response. This is especially true because many of us work so hard to provide great solutions whenever we can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO *just* pointing to an app (i.e., pre-edit) is an appropriate *comment*, but it's not an answer.

*Post*-edit (i.e., the theory) is a better answer: although not an actual *answer*, it would have been impossible to read as a comment. Although step 4 reads as either "then a miracle occurs" or "Step 3: ???", which is a little sketchy--as it's the *key* to answering the question.

I also don't see Nokolay's comment as anything other than what it was--questioning the usefulness and validity of the answer. IMO the response was reasonable, and measured.

Comment: I agree with every point. I have, however, seen accepted answers where someone merely pointed the way. This is how I was trying to help this individual

Comment: Regarding the other poster. Fair enough! I shouldn't take offense and should just consider it as further discussion. Thanks for your opinion.

Comment: @FuzzicalLogic The act of accepting an answer doesn't mean it's good, or appropriate :) I don't think providing ideas or theories is *intrinsically* bad, but it depends--and as with anything here, someone might not share the same view.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't a community faux pas. Based on the link you provided, however, it goes against my own ethics to keep that post. (While I may respect a developer's *ability* to circumvent the system, I do not publicly *advocate* any developer purposefully circumventing the intention of the system.)